# ASP.NET MVC Error Page Being Found but getting Elmah Email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, elmah

I have an error page located at Errors/Error in my ErrorsController.  If I create an error it redirects me to that page fine.  However I get a error email from Elmah stating the message below.  Is there a reason why I am getting this message even thought my error page displayed fine?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/divisions/Error.cshtml ~/Views/divisions/Error.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml
```

**Web.Config**

```
   <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/PageNotFound" />
      </customErrors>
```

Comment: These should not be at the root.  They have to be in the Views\divisions or Views\Shared folder.  The reason it's displaying is likely because IIS is showing it, bypassing MVC.

Comment: Add your Elmah web.config portion, if it's sending you emails, then it's configured to do so.

Comment: what do you mean 'if you create an error'?

Comment: If I go to a controller action that does supply a correct parameter it will throw an error and redirecto my error page.